# Calling Embedded Lightning Component from the Parent Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a Lightning component (parent), and it has another Lightning component embedded within it:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">

  <!-- markup above -->
    <c:CaptchaComponent aura:id="captcha" />
  <!-- markup below-->

</aura:component>
```

The CaptchaComponent has a button (aura:id="myButton"). I want to be able to enabled/disable that button from the parent Lightning component's controller. I was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
var captchaCmp = component.find("captcha");
captchaCmp.myButton.set("v.diabled", false);
```

What's the correct way of calling that from the parent component?

Comment: One of the better way would be to declare an [`aura:method`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_method.htm) in child component, and call it from parent component.

Comment: @Matt Smith, Aura components also support 2 way binding, so, you can add a  `isDisabled` attribute to your Captcha component

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aura:method to achieve this. In the aura method defined in your child component's JavaScript (controller/helper), you can set an attribute which will in turn enable/ disable the button. Please refer the below link to learn more about aura:method.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_method.htm